# How to make a class class be dispached on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've a custom class to hold data and I want to dispatch it into a job, but every time that I try i got this error:

> Object of class App\Gateways\Partner\Entities\PartnerData could not be converted to string

The class:

```
class PartnerData
{
    public string $name;
    public string $phone;

    public function __construct($info)
    {
        $this->name = $info['name'];
        $this->phone = $info['phone'];
    }
}
```

The job class:

```
class MyJob implements ShouldQueue {

   // traits imported...
 
   private PartnerData $partner;

   public function __construct(PartnerData $partner)
   {
       $this->partner = $parner;
   }

   public function handle()
   {
       // Process partner data
   }
}
```

The code:

```php
collect($datas)
    ->mapInto(PartnerData::class)
    ->each(fn(PartnerData $pd) => MyJob::dispatch($pd));
```

There's a similar question without a awnser here: [Laravel Queue not able to convert class object to string how can i dispatch that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435824/laravel-queue-not-able-to-convert-class-object-to-string-how-can-i-dispatch-that)

How can I make the class `PartnerData` dispatchable/stringable ?

Comment: Can u provide `MyJob` job's logic (Especially its `__constructor` method) ?

Comment: `PartnerData` is the class you are trying to dispatch. But I need to see your job class's inside. Most probably you have defined `__constructor` method in `MyJob` class that is supposed to receive string not `PartnerData ` object

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli yes, my job class have a constructor receiving an instance of `PartnerData`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to dispatch an array of jobs by using each method to dispatch each of them. Alternatively, maybe you can use Bus::batch() to dispatch an array of jobs.

for example:

```
$jobArray = $this->createJobsArray($someValue);

Bus::batch($jobArray)->onQueue('selected-queue')->dispatch();
```